# Why I obtain this error when I put a null value into the Spring MVC model object? java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute value must not be null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am pretty new with **FreeMarker** and I am working on a **Spring MVC** application that use **FreeMarker** as template engine.

So I have the following problem tryng to put a null value into the model and trying to evaluate it into my **FreeMarker** page.

So I have the following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sso/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginPost(HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute DoLoginCommand command, 
        @ModelAttribute("redirect") String redirect, Model model) {

    ...................................................................
    ...................................................................
    ...................................................................

    if (statusPasswordView.getDataWarning() != null && statusPasswordView.getDataWarning().before(new Date())) {
        model.addAttribute(MA_EXPIRE_DATE, dataScadenza);

        if(redirect.equals("")) {
            model.addAttribute("redirect", null);
        }
        else {
            model.addAttribute("redirect", redirect);
        }

        return "/sso/password-toexpire";
    }
    ...................................................................
    ...................................................................
    ...................................................................
}
```

So, as you can see in the previous code snippet, the **loginPost()** method receive as parameter this String **@ModelAttribute("redirect") String redirect** (that is a **@SessionAttributes** of my controller class but I think that this is not important now).

If the value of the **redirect** variable is an empty String (the "" string) I put in the model an attribite named **redirect** having **null** as value. 
Else if the **redirect** string is not the empty string I put it value as value of the previous **redirect** model attribute.

Then into my **FreeMarker** page (named **password-toexpire.ftl**) I do:

```
    <#if redirect??>
        <a href="<@spring.url '/profilo/home' />" class="btn btn-block btn-success submit-btn">Continua la navigazione</a>
    <#else>
        <a href="${redirect}" class="btn btn-block btn-success submit-btn">Continua la navigazione</a>
    </#if>
```

So, in this page, I am checking if the **redirect** attribute is **null** or not to render different element into my final HTML.

The only problem is that when my **password-toexpire.ftl** page is returned I obtain thi error message into the Eclipse stack trace:

```
14:48:44,092 ERROR [it.mycompany.myprogjet.mypackage.base.SsumExceptionHandlerControllerAdvise] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Attribute value must not be null: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute value must not be null
```

So it seems that in Spring I can't put **null** attribute into the **model** onject but it seems strange to me.

Why? What is the problem? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes:

- If you want a model attribute to be empty, you don't need to manually put `null` in it. It's better to just omit the whole attribute.
- In your template you are checking if the attribute exists (is non-null) - but in your else branch (if you've determined that `redirect` does not exist) you are evaluating it anyway for your `<a href=${redirect}>` element. This is unlikely to do what you want.

Also instead of the `redirect??` for the existence check, you could pass the empty string along to the attribute and use `redirect?has_content` instead, which returns false if the attribute does not exist, is `null`, or is empty (in the case of a `String`, its length is zero).